# Setting AM/PM of TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, datetime, dialog

When using `TimePickerDialog` everything seems to work right except that the first time it is run, it assumes that the current AM/PM is AM even if it isn't.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case TIME_DIALOG:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeSetter, hour, minute, false);
    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetter =  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int cHour, int cMinute)
    {
        hour = cHour;
        minute = cMinute;
    }
};
```

Once a time has been chosen, the AM/PM setting is correct on consecutive runs, but I don't know how to set it to the proper AM/PM. Help?

Comment: Me too facing this issue..any insights on this plz..?

Comment: Nope, I think this is a bug ...